# Fixed div width is wider than the screen

Tags: html, css

I am trying to fix a div with a `50vw` width. However, when I fix the div, `50vw` acts as if it's `100vw`.

In the example below, to get the effect I want, I have to make the `target` `25vw` instead of `50vw`. `100vw` is wider than the screen.

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gncy93fr/). the blue `.target` container should be half the width of the yellow container.

```html
<div class="main">
    .
    <div class="content"> 
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="target-containers">
                <div class="target">. </div>     
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

CSS

```css
html, body {      
  margin: 0;
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color:gray;
}

.main {
  background-color: yellow;
  min-height:100vw;
  position:relative; 
  margin-left: 25%;
  margin-right:25%;
}

.content-wrappers {
    position:relative;
}

.target-containers {
    position:relative;
}

.target { 
    min-width:50%;
    width:50%;
    position:fixed;
    float:left;
    background-color:blue; 
}
```

Comment: Seems to work fine [here](https://jsfiddle.net/u73hwkeL/)

Comment: The width of the blue bar is supposed to be 50% of the yellow container.

Answer (score 0):

Please read about [position: fixed.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#fixed)

> It is positioned relative to the initial containing block established by the viewport, except when one of its ancestors has a transform, perspective, or filter property set to something other than none

---

Who is the initial containing block? (EDIT to clearify [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61066272/fixed-div-width-is-wider-than-the-screen/61066874?noredirect=1#comment108036827_61066874#comment-108036827))

Please read about [identifying the containing block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Containing_block#Identifying_the_containing_block)

> Note: The containing block in which the root element () resides is a rectangle called the initial containing block. It has the dimensions of the viewport (for continuous media) or the page area (for paged media).

Please read about [position: sticky](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-position-3/#sticky-pos)

> A stickily positioned box is positioned similarly to a relatively positioned box, but the offset is computed with reference to the nearest ancestor with a scrolling box, or the viewport if no ancestor has a scrolling box.

You could change the position value to sticky like this

```
.main {
    background-color: yellow;
    max-height:100vh;  
    min-height: 100vh;
    margin-left: 25%;
    margin-right:25%;
    overflow-y: auto
 }

 .target{ 
    min-width:50%;
    width:50%;
    position:sticky;
    background-color:blue;
    top: 0;
 }
```

[Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/wbqxcf5k/)

Comment: Thank you this works, but by ` initial containing block`, does that include `body` or `html`? When I set the width for `body, htlml` to 100vw, this does not fix the issue?

Comment: @auto, Added an edit to clearify who the initial containing block is, which in this case is the html tag that already has the dimentions of the viewport. So, there is no need to specify that in your css, wont you agree? And i thought the issue was **one fixed-width div wider than its container**, right?.

Comment: Sorry, have to edit that while this resizes the div properly, it does not keep the container fixed. https://jsfiddle.net/n4koz27w/

Answer (score -1):

If you make an element `position:fixed` it will break it out of the document flow.

If you remove `position: fixed` it works as expected as it is inheriting from the parent element.

https://jsfiddle.net/k460abmv/

Comment: Document flow not stacking context.

Comment: Plus arguably the answer was correct:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context

Weird to get downvoted for posting the first correct answer with a working example.

Comment: `position:fixed` makes the element get out of the document flow meaning it wont affect other elements, `Stacking context` is something an element establishes within it, it has nothing to with layout, I suspect your answer got downvoted because the op wants to make use of position fixed to make the element fix his problem is with it's width not it's position. Don't take downvotes as a hate-crime they're merely guidelines we all have them.